# How can I speed up a multiple inner join query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.  The first table (users) is a simple "id, username" with 100,00 rows and the second (stats) is "id, date, stat" with 20M rows.

I'm trying to figure out which username went up by the most in stat and here's the query I have.  On a powerful machine, this query takes minutes to complete.  Is there a better way to write it to speed it up?

```
SELECT a.id, a.username, b.stat, c.stat, (b.stat - c.stat) AS stat_diff
FROM users AS a
INNER JOIN stats AS b ON (b.id=a.id)
INNER JOIN stats AS c ON (c.id=a.id)
WHERE b.date = '2016-01-10'
AND c.date = '2016-01-13'
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY stat_diff DESC
LIMIT 100
```

the other way i tried but it doesn't seem optimal is

```
SELECT a.id, a.username, 
     (SELECT b.stat FROM stats AS b ON (b.id=a.id) AND b.date = '2016-01-10') AS start,
     (SELECT c.stat FROM stats AS c ON (c.id=a.id) AND c.date = '2016-01-14') AS end,
     ((SELECT b.stat FROM stats AS b ON (b.id=a.id) AND b.date = '2016-01-10') - 
      (SELECT c.stat FROM stats AS c ON (c.id=a.id) AND c.date = '2016-01-14')) AS stat_diff
FROM users AS a
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY stat_diff DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: can you `EXPLAIN` your query then post the result here

Comment: I guess my question is why you feel the need to run so many repetitive inner queries on your select statement.

Comment: Is the group by necessary? Are there indexes on the id and datefields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Introduction**

Let's suppose we rewrite sentence like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.username, b.stat, c.stat, (b.stat - c.stat) AS stat_diff
FROM users AS a
INNER JOIN stats AS b ON 
    b.date = STR_TO_DATE('2016-01-10', '%Y-%m-%d' ) and b.id=a.id
INNER JOIN stats AS c ON 
    c.date = STR_TO_DATE('2016-01-13', '%Y-%m-%d' ) and c.id=a.id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY stat_diff DESC
LIMIT 100
```

And we ensure than:

- `users` table has index on field `id`:
- `stats` has index on composite field `date`, `id`:  `create index stats_idx_d_i on stats ( date, id );`

**Then**

Database optimizer may use indexes to selected a Restricted Set of Date  (**'RSD'**), that means, rows that match filtered dates. This is fast.

**But**

You are sorting by a calculated field:

```
 (b.stat - c.stat) AS stat_diff   #<-- calculated 
 ORDER BY stat_diff DESC          #<-- this forces to calculate it
```

They are no possible optimization on this sort because you should to calculate one by one all results on your **'RSD'** (restricted set of data).

**Conclusion**

The question is, how may rows they are on your **'RSD'**? If only they are few hundreds rows you query may run fast, else, your query will be slow.

Any case, you should to be sure the first step of query ( without sorting ) is made by index and no fullscanning. Use [`Explain`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) command to be sure.

Comment: This is what I suspected.  I'm just surprised that on a machine with 50GB free ram and a lot of CPU and only 20M rows, it takes a minute and a half :(

Comment: I have more performance on this kind of queries on PostgeSql. Also you can materialitze results on a indexed precalculated table or view.

Answer (score 0):

The Query Seems OK, Verify your Indexes ..

Or
Try this Query

```
SELECT a.id, a.username, b.stat, c.stat, (b.stat - c.stat) AS stat_diff
FROM users AS a
INNER JOIN (select id,stat from stats where date = '2016-01-10') AS b ON (b.id=a.id)
INNER JOIN (select id,stat from stats where date = '2016-01-13') AS c ON (c.id=a.id)
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY stat_diff DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: FYI:with inner join and where clauses are same

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to help optimizer.At a bare minimum.have a check list which looks like below

1.Are my join columns indexed ?
2.Are the where clauses Sargable
3.are there any implicit,explicit conversions
4.Am i seeing any statistics issues

one more interesting aspect to look at is how is your data distributed,once you understand the data,you will be able to intrepret the execution plan and alter it as per your need

**EX:**
Think like i have any customers table with 100rows,Each one has a minimum of 10 orders(total upto 10000 orders).Now if you need to find out only top  3 orders by date,you dont want a scan happening of orders table

Now in your case ,i may not go with second option,even though the optimizer may choose a good plan for this one as well,I will go first approach  and try to see if the execution time is acceptable.if not then i will go through my check list and try to tune it further

Comment: +1.  I'd start with indexing.  Are you working with Primary Keys at all?  Also, depending on whether or not you specified CLUSTERED or NONCLUSTERED identifiers, sequencing can slow down your query, because as @TheGameiswar mentioned, table scans each time you execute your query will impact performance